# Look-Around Regex having text in between

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have log entries and I want to find the rows containing `[ERR]` but not `IsLocked`.

Example rows:

```
12:54:30 [INF] [Thread 2] Program started
12:54:30 [ERR] [Thread 1] IsLocked  
12:54:30 [ERR] [Thread 3] Internal Error
```

I want to find the 3rd row only with my regex. I tried

```
\[ERR\](?!IsLocked)
```

But that does not work since there is text between `[ERR]` and `IsLocked`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
\[ERR\]((?!IsLocked).)*$
```

It looks for the string following the next character, and if it's not `IsLocked`, it goes on to match next character. It does this pre-check for every character matched till the end.